# How to do string interpolation in raw strings in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I can do the string interpolation using **$** sign in normal strings

but how can I perform interpolation in raw strings.

**`r"this is a raw string"`**

because **$** sign for interpolation is not working in raw strings like this

**`r"my name is $name"`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, according to language specification it wouldn't work from within the raw string. However you could do this:

```
r"my name is ""$name"r". Blah blah.";
```

Comment: It is not working, because we have to interpolate the raw string inside a string and I am not able to figure out that, how to convert string to raw string in dart

Comment: @PriyanshuPaliwal, are you sure of that. The sample I provided works exactly fine for me.

Comment: Sorry I didn't tried it correctly. It works Thankyou :)